# Printing array in format breaks for larger integers

Tags: assembly, mips

I have an array that contains the fibbonaci sequence. When I print the contents I do that in a format:

> array[0] = 1
>
> ...
>
> array[4] = 5
>
> ...

So besides printing the array's contents, I am printing a message for "array[" then the index which
is just printing a register counter, and then the last part "] = " and then I print the array's value. For size larger than 6, this is not working, specifically the latter part "] = " is not printing and the value of the array is being concatenated to the index.

This is the code that prints the value:

```
.data
    arrayF: .word # starting address of array
    prompt: .asciiz "Enter value of N: "
    stringPartTwo: .asciiz "] = "
    stringPartOne: .asciiz "array["

.text
    start:
        # for printing the prompt
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, prompt
        syscall

        # getting N from user
        li $v0, 5
        syscall
        move $t0, $v0 # putting N's value in $t0

        # Loading the beginning address of array into $a1 and $a2
        la $a1, arrayF
        addi $t1, $zero, 0 # A[i - 2]
        addi $t2, $zero, 0 # A[i - 1]
        addi $t3, $zero, 1 # A[i]
        addi $t4, $t0, 0 # Saves size of array in another register for later subroutine


   loop1:
        beq $t0, 0, done # Checking if size reached to 0
        subi $t0, $t0, 1 # Decrementing size for next iteration
        sw $t3, ($a1) # Storing A[i] in the array
        addi $a1, $a1, 4 # Accessing next element in array
        addi $t1, $t2, 0 # Moving A[i - 1] to A[i - 2] 
        addi $t2, $t3, 0 # Moving A[i] to A[i - 1]
        add $t3, $t2, $t1 # Calculating new A[i] 
        j loop1

    done:
        la $a1, arrayF # Loading base address
        addi $t1, $zero, 0 # Counter for subroutine

   loop2:
        beq $t1, $t4, finish # done printing if reached array's length
        lw $t2, ($a1) # loading the value in A[i] to $t2

        # printing "array["
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, stringPartOne
        syscall

        # print index
        li $v0, 1 
        move $a0, $t1
        syscall 

        # printing "] = "
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, stringPartTwo
        syscall

        # print value of array
        li $v0, 1 
        move $a0, $t2
        syscall 

        # printing new line
        addi $a0, $0, 10     #put newline in a0
        addi $v0, $0, 11     #print character in a0
        syscall


        addi $t1, $t1, 1 # incrementing counter
        addi $a1, $a1, 4 # accessing next element
        j loop2
```

Output snips:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sounds to me like you haven't allocated enough memory for the array to hold 7 elements, so you end up overwriting other things in your data section. But it's hard to say because you haven't shown us your entire program.

Comment: The array has enough memory to hold 7 elements, the issue rises only when I try to put that in the format I showed above

Comment: Well, no one will be able to reproduce that issue without having all the code.

Comment: I added all code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've only allocated a single word (4 bytes) of space for your array. Trying to store more than that will overwite first `prompt`, and then `stringPartTwo` and `stringPartOne` depending on how many words you attempt to store.

You need to allocate more memory for your array, for example:

```
arrayF: .space 64   # allocate 64 bytes (16 words)
```